# Running .exe with Mono on Debian - System.DllNotFoundException: libgda-2.so.3

Tags: c#, linux, mono, foxpro, dbf

I've written a C# application on Windows that fetches a DataTable from a .DBF file, and it works fine on Windows.
The MoMA says that it should work with Mono, but running it on Debian with `mono Terminal.exe` gives me the following:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: libgda-2.so.3
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.OleDb.libgda:gda_init (string,string,int,string[])
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Helper.GetOrder () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Terminalen..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: libgda-2.so.3
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.OleDb.libgda:gda_init (string,string,int,string[])
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Helper.GetOrder () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Terminalen..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Terminal.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've tried installing a bunch of packages that sound close to `libgda`but I can't seem to get it to work. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.gnome-db.org/ / https://github.com/GNOME/libgda